# Remove distortion from image using php

Tags: php, image, captcha

I am beginner to PHP image processing. I have an image, I have to remove the distortion from that image and read the date. How can I do that in PHP.

[image]

How can I remove destortion from that image and read the date.

Comment: Its a time warp..... [kidding]

Comment: Did you add that distortion in the first place to the image?

Comment: distortion is done, but not added by me

Comment: Is that a captcha generated by some site?

Comment: Wanna pay for it? https://krebsonsecurity.com/2012/01/virtual-sweatshops-defeat-bot-or-not-tests/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+KrebsOnSecurity+%28Krebs+on+Security%29

Answer (score 3):

There simply isn't any *one method fits all* type answer. Unless you write some amazingly complicated code that can pick the distortion applied, relate it back on a pixel by pixel basis to what the original was meant to be, you will make buckets of money getting past all the CAPTCHAS used for exactly that purpose - to make sure a human is driving the wheel, not a bit of code.

In theory, you could write a bit of code to apply the opposite of that exact distortion fairly easily, looks like nothing more than a repeated drag has been added to that image - but that will work for that EXACT image, and will likely just make the next image even more distorted.

Comment: can i remove destortion using MATLAB ?